# AucTeX fails to generate previews on Mac OS X

Tags: mac, auctex, preview

When I try to generate the previews for the document on my Mac I get the following error on the preview:

```
/usr/texbin/rungs -dOutputFile\=\(review.prv/tmp7722b0S/pr1-27.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r110.418x110.464
GS>{<</PermitFileReading[(review.pdf)(review.prv/tmp7722b0S/preview.dsc)]>> setuserparams .locksafe} stopped pop {DELAYSAFER{.setsafe}if}stopped pop/.preview-BP currentpagedevice/BeginPage get dup null eq{pop{pop}bind}if def<</BeginPage{currentpagedevice/PageSize get dup 0 get 1 ne exch 1 get 1 ne or{.preview-BP 0.14844 0.195315 0.218753 setrgbcolor clippath fill 0.996109 0.996109 0.996109 setrgbcolor}{pop}ifelse}bind/PageSize[1 1]>>setpagedevice/preview-do{[count 3 roll save]3 1 roll dup length 0 eq{pop}{setpagedevice}{ifelse .runandhide}stopped{handleerror quit}if aload pop restore}bind def /GS_PDF_ProcSet GS_PDF_ProcSet dup maxlength dict copy dup begin/graphicsbeginpage{//graphicsbeginpage exec 0.996109 0.996109 0.996109 3 copy rg RG}bind store end readonly store [(review.prv/tmp7722b0S/preview.dsc)(r)file]aload exch dup 0 setfileposition 5581()/SubFileDecode filter cvx .runandhide aload pop dup dup 5897 setfileposition 53()/SubFileDecode filter cvx<<>>preview-do
Error: /typecheck in --setfileposition--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   7186   7186   7186   7131   7131   7131   7078   7078   7078   7296   7296   7296   7023   7023   7023   6967   6967   6967   6912   6912   6912   6858   6858   6858   6802   6802   6802   6749   6749   6749   6696   6696   6696   6642   6642   6642   6588   6588   6588   6535   6535   6535   6482   6482   6482   6428   6428   6428   6372   6372   6372   6321   6321   6321   6265   6265   6265   6211   6211   6211   6158   6158   6158   6105   6105   6105   6049   6049   6049   6000   6000   6000   5950   5950   5950   5897
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1158/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--   --dict:108/127(ro)(L)--   --dict:288/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:20/25(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 29
GS<79>
```

I checked AucTeX installation guide for Mac OS X, it was suggested that direct route to generate PDF on Mac may be a bit wonky, and it can be changed via `Menu -> Command -> TeXing options`. If I uncheck option `Generate PDF` there I can see the previews for inline math and `equation*` environment. The previews for numbered equations and section headers now have the error:

```
/usr/texbin/rungs -dOutputFile\=\(review.prv/tmp7722o-Y/pr2-9.png\) -q -dDELAYSAFER -dNOPAUSE -DNOPLATFONTS -dPrinted -dTextAlphaBits\=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits\=4 -sDEVICE\=png16m -r110.418x110.464
GS>{<</PermitFileReading[(review.prv/tmp7722o-Y/preview.ps)]>> setuserparams .locksafe} stopped pop {DELAYSAFER{.setsafe}if}stopped pop/.preview-BP currentpagedevice/BeginPage get dup null eq{pop{pop}bind}if def<</BeginPage{currentpagedevice/PageSize get dup 0 get 1 ne exch 1 get 1 ne or{.preview-BP 0.14844 0.195315 0.218753 setrgbcolor clippath fill 0.996109 0.996109 0.996109 setrgbcolor}{pop}ifelse}bind/PageSize[1 1]>>setpagedevice/preview-do{[count 3 roll save]3 1 roll dup length 0 eq{pop}{setpagedevice}{ifelse .runandhide}stopped{handleerror quit}if aload pop restore}bind def [(review.prv/tmp7722o-Y/preview.ps)(r)file]aload exch dup 0 setfileposition 189571()/SubFileDecode filter cvx .runandhide aload pop dup dup 193963 setfileposition 504()/SubFileDecode filter cvx<<>>preview-do
Error: /undefined in H.S
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1148   --nostringval--   %end_runandhide   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1158/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--   --dict:123/300(L)--   --dict:19/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2

Preview-Ghostscript finished
```

The same error shows if I use indirect way of generating PDF (I guess this would be expected as it goes via Ghostscript as well).

I can generate the previews for the same document on my Linux machine. So, I guess, something is wrong with my Emacs-AucTeX-TeXLive-Ghostscript setup.

- Emacs 24.4.1 (from homebrew)
- AucTeX 11.89.5 (from MELPA)
- TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2010)
- gs 8.71 (from homebrew)

PS. I am not sure what AucTeX uses to generate PDF previews.

Does something have an incompatible version?

Comment: Was solved by updating Ghostscript and making sure the latest version is used.